# Ubuntu VNC doesnt start gnome

Tags: gnome, nautilus, remote-desktop, vnc

I have Ubuntu 22.04 AWS instance with the following ~/.vnc/xstartup config:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

I took the config from here https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-desktop-aws#3-configuring-the-vnc-server

When I open VNC session I expect to see the GNOME desktop (which i see if i use RDP). Instead I see
[this GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhQ8j.png)

How can I fix that ?